# Обращение iframe и родительского окна с разных доменов

Tags: javascript

Есть любой сайт, на него вставляется такой код виджета:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//site.com/widget.js"></script>
<div id="co_group"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
   CO.public_widget('{"id":"1","color1":"FFFFFF","color2":"2B587A","color3":"5B7FA6","width":220,"height":400,"mode":"2"}', 'co_group');
</script>
```

Он создает `iframe` с нужным `src` и нужно чтобы `iframe` открывал окошко с контентом на домене на который он встроен, я добавил в **widget.js** такой код, который создает окошко:

```
function box_wid_pub_opn_photo(url){
   var elemDiv = document.createElement('div');
   elemDiv.id = "box_wid_p";
   elemDiv.style.cssText = 'position: fixed; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 999; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)';
   document.body.appendChild(elemDiv);
   document.getElementById('box_wid_p').innerHTML = '<div id="wind_wid_pv" style="margin: 20px auto; width: 800px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; padding: 20px;"><div style="color: #21578B;font-weight: bold;padding-bottom: 10px;padding-top: 10px;">Просмотр фотографии <a style="float:right;font-weight: normal;" onclick="close_box_wid_pub_opn_photo(); return false;" href="" onclick="">Закрыть</a></div><div style="text-align: center;"><img src="'+url+'" alt=""/></div></div>';
}
function close_box_wid_pub_opn_photo(){
   document.getElementById('box_wid_p').remove();
}
```

Вызываю создание окошка из `iframe` так

```
window.parent.box_wid_pub_opn_photo('site.com/img.png');
```

если испытываю на сайте с на котором расположен URL  из `iframe`, то все нормально, но если же с другого, то получаю ошибку

> Error: Permission denied to access property "box_wid_pub_opn_photo"

Comment: В вашем случае это ограничение безопасности браузера.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript не может напрямую взаимодействовать между разными доменами – это [правило ограничения домена](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0), и браузеры его выполняют.

Надо, чтобы помимо кода виджета на сайте вставлялась функция открытия окна, и слушатель сообщений [`postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) изнутри iFrame.

Comment: "ф-я" - что это?

Comment: «ф-я» – это  «функция». Простите, поправил ответ.